# Microsoft Health SDK expired SSL Certificate

Tags: microsoft-band

It appears that some subset of our requests to Microsoft Health's SDK is failing due to an SSL certificate being expired -- I've not yet been able to reproduce this in a web browser but our code is seeing this a lot since yesterday.

java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Tue Dec 19 12:06:55 PST 2017

Eric

Comment: The easiest way to reliably repro is via wget or lynx to 'https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Activities'

Comment: You can see the full certificate chain on https://www.digicert.com/help/ which shows that the chain expired yesterday:

Subject Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
Valid from 19/Dec/2013 to 19/Dec/2017
Issuer Baltimore CyberTrust Root

Comment: The SSL certificate appears to have been renewed on 2018-01-05. Are you still seeing those failures in your app?

Comment: @IInspectable I am no longer seeing this issue. If you do work on this team, we are receiving lots of timeouts from the service for unknown reasons though.

Comment: I'm just an independent developer accessing the Microsoft Health Cloud API myself. I haven't seen any timeouts so far. If you do, you'd have to contact Microsoft using one of the official communication channels.